# Let's do something better with all those high-voted old closed questions

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, review-audits, vote-to-reopen

The reopen queue seems to be flooded with old high-popularity open-ended questions. I just NoActionNeeded'd and downvoted 20 of them. Instead of putting posts in the queue to consider reopening when every one of them is obviously close-worth by today's standards (good job with the algorithm consistency), can we make them audits? I've seen people reopening them for some reason, they should be review banned.