# An influx of reopen votes

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen

Just was going through reopen queue and it seems like one person (or not one) has cast a reopen vote on lots of recommendation & open-ended questions.

Can someone with higher privileges please check out what's going on?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258140/2888561

Comment: Yeah, it was at 90 or so earlier. I noticed that both the reopen and VLQ queues have had this "blips" for the past few days.

Comment: They're not in there because of reopen votes - they're in there because highly-voted "popular" questions are automatically fed into that queue.